# How to provide an HttpClient to ktor server from the outside to facilitate mocking external services?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I am trying to provide an `HttpClient` from the outside to my ktor server so that I can mock [external services](https://ktor.io/docs/testing.html#external-services) and write tests, however I get this exception when I run my test:

```bash
Please make sure that you use unique name for the plugin and don't install it twice. Conflicting application plugin is already installed with the same key as `Compression`
io.ktor.server.application.DuplicatePluginException: Please make sure that you use unique name for the plugin and don't install it twice. Conflicting application plugin is already installed with the same key as `Compression`
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.ApplicationPluginKt.install(ApplicationPlugin.kt:112)
    at app//com.example.plugins.HTTPKt.configureHTTP(HTTP.kt:13)
    at app//com.example.ApplicationKt.module(Application.kt:14)
    at app//com.example.ApplicationTest$expected to work$1$1.invoke(ApplicationTest.kt:39)
    at app//com.example.ApplicationTest$expected to work$1$1.invoke(ApplicationTest.kt:38)
```

and thats a bit unexpected to me because I am not applying the `Compression` plugin twice as far as I can tell. If I run the server normally and manually call my endpoint with `curl` then it works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

I added a runnable sample project [here with a failing test](https://github.com/sphrak/ktor-server-httpclient/blob/trunk/src/test/kotlin/com/example/ApplicationTest.kt#L23).

- [sample project](https://github.com/sphrak/ktor-server-httpclient)
- official [ktor-documentation-sample](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/2.1.2/codeSnippets/snippets/auth-oauth-google/src/test/kotlin/ApplicationTest.kt#L18) project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `application.conf` file and by default, the `testApplication` function tries to load modules which are enumerated there. Since you also explicitly load them in the `application {}` block the `DuplicatePluginException` occurs. To solve your problem you can explicitly load an empty configuration instead of the default one:

```
// ...
application {
    module(client)
}

environment {
    config = MapApplicationConfig()
}
// ...
```